# Spring Data Cassandra config change on the fly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to do a similar thing with my application. I am using following versions of Spring boot and Cassandra:

spring-data-cassandra - 2.0.8.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter-parent - 2.0.4.RELEASE
I need to change some properties(mostly hostnames) of Cassandra on the fly and want it to make a new connection with the application. For config change we have internal Cloud Config Change Management and it runs fine on changes and listens to it. 
This is my class :

```
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RefreshScope
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = {"com.*.*.*.dao.repo"})
public class AppConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);

    @Value("${application['cassandraPort']}")
    private String cassandraPort;

    @Value("${application['cassandraEndpoint']}")
    private String cassandraEndpoint;

    @Value("${application['keyspaceName']}")
    private String keyspaceName;

    @Value("${application['cassandraConsistency']}")
    private String cassandraConsistency;

    @Value("${application['cassandraUserName']}")
    private String cassandraUserName;




    @Autowired
    private AppConfig appConfig;


    public AppConfig() {

        System.out.println("AppConfig Constructor");

    }




    public String getCassandraPort() {
        return cassandraPort;
    }

    public void setCassandraPort(String cassandraPort) {
        this.cassandraPort = cassandraPort;
    }

    public String getCassandraEndpoint() {
        return cassandraEndpoint;
    }

    public void setCassandraEndpoint(String cassandraEndpoint) {
        this.cassandraEndpoint = cassandraEndpoint;
    }

    public String getKeyspaceName() {
        return keyspaceName;
    }

    public void setKeyspaceName(String keyspaceName) {
        this.keyspaceName = keyspaceName;
    }

    public String getCassandraConsistency() {
        return cassandraConsistency;
    }

    public void setCassandraConsistency(String cassandraConsistency) {
        this.cassandraConsistency = cassandraConsistency;
    }

    public String getCassandraUserName() {
        return cassandraUserName;
    }

    public void setCassandraUserName(String cassandraUserName) {
        this.cassandraUserName = cassandraUserName;
    }




    @Bean
    // @RefreshScope
    public CassandraConverter converter() {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(this.mappingContext());
    }


    @Bean
    // @RefreshScope
    public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
        return new CassandraMappingContext();
    }


    @Bean
    //@RefreshScope
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() {


        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();

        session.setCluster(this.cluster().getObject());
        session.setKeyspaceName(appConfig.getKeyspaceName());
        session.setConverter(this.converter());
        session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);
        return session;
    }

    @Bean
    //@RefreshScope
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();

        cluster.setContactPoints(appConfig.getCassandraEndpoint());
        cluster.setPort(Integer.valueOf(appConfig.getCassandraPort()));
        cluster.setUsername(appConfig.getCassandraUserName());
        cluster.setPassword("password");
        cluster.setQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM));

        return cluster;
    }

}
```

However, when I try to use @RefreshScope with that Configuration class, the application fails to start. This is what it shows in console :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 2 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'cassandraCluster' not loaded because auto-configuration 'CassandraAutoConfiguration' was excluded


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster' in your configuration.
```

Is there some guidelines on using @RefreshScope with Cassandra Bean? If anyone has done that earlier can you share the same?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing a couple of things here.

1. The config carries properties and bean definitions.
2. `@RefreshScope` on `AppConfig` causes some interference with Spring Boot's auto-configuration and the declared beans aren't used (that's why you see `Parameter 2 of constructor…`).

To clean up, we will reuse what Spring Boot provides as much as possible, and **only** declare what's really needed.

Follow these steps to solve the issue (based on your code above):

1. Create a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean that encapsulates your properties, or better, reuse `CassandraProperties`.
2. Re-enable `CassandraAutoConfiguration` and remove your own `MappingContext` and `CassandraConverter` beans, keep only `Cluster` and `Session` bean definitions
3. Declare `Cluster` and `Session` beans as needed and make them use `@RefreshScope`. Your `@Configuration` class should look like:

Example Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    @RefreshScope
    public Cluster cassandraCluster(CassandraProperties properties) {
        Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(properties.getContactPoints().toArray(new String[0]))
                .withoutJMXReporting();

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    @RefreshScope
    public Session cassandraSession(CassandraProperties properties, Cluster cluster) {
        return cluster.connect(properties.getKeyspaceName());
    }
}
```